# Django: Recommended Model definitions for Customers and Payments when handling recurring payments

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have two models, one for `Customer` and another for `Payment`.  Each month my `customer` should have made a payment no later that the 15th of each month. What is the best way to structure the models in order to easily get a report of customers who haven't pay for the current month?

Customer model:

```
class CustomerModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField()
    last_name = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Payment model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
               Customer,
               on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
               null=True) 
    amount = models.FloatField()
    date_received = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
```

Comment: Say it is october 12th, then most `Customer`s will not have paid for that month, should we then "list" these? Does the "amount" plays any role here (what if it is zero, or negative)?

Comment: How do you know what month the payment is for? What if someone pays on the 2nd October? Is he paying for the previous month or for this month? What’s the exact problem you’re having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of `.exclude(..)` here to exclude the people that *have* paid, like:

```
from datetime import date
month_day = date.today()            # specify a day in the month to check
from_date=month_day.replace(day=1)  # the first of the current month
to_date=month_day.replace(day=15)   # the 15th of the current month

Customer.objects.exclude(
    payment__date_received__gte=from_date
    payment__date_received__lte=to_date
)
```

or more elegant with a `__range` lookup:

```
Customer.objects.exclude(
    payment__date_received__range=(from_date, to_date)
)
```

If we thus run this today (with `month_day` equal to the 15th of October, 2018), we will get all `Customer`s that have *not* made a `payment` with `date_received` between the *first* of October, and the 15th of October. The same will happen any day of this month. By setting `month_day` to for example `date(2017, 12)`, you obtain all the customers that did not make a payment between December 1st, 2017 and December 15th, 2017.

Note hwever that perhaps *not* all customers started using your service at that moment (or already unsubscribed). In that case these `Customer`s will thus get listed, so it might require some refactoring to make this more usable.